# Using network analyst new closest facility to calculate certain routes but not others?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I'm working on calculating a variety of distances between many points using network analyst using ArcGIS 10.2. Using the new closest facility option, I have 100,000 facilities and 100,000 incidents, and I want to calculate specific routes: Location 1 to Location 1, Location 2 to Location 2, etc. I don't care about calculating Location 1 to Location 3 or 4 - I only care about the distance between the corresponding locations.

I'm planning on using a workaround, where I set the "facilities to find" under Analysis Settings to 100,000, and then just deleting out all of the irrelevant results once the model is finished. This would be much more efficient, though, if I could only calculate the 100,000 I care about, instead of the 10 billion it will calculate otherwise. Is there an easy way to restrict this, either by using new closest facility or some other Network Analyst capability? Thanks.

The screenshot shows my (probably) flawed method that I've been trying to use in a test case I did before doing the 100,000 - when I have 5 facilities and 5 locations I ask the model to find five facilities, which gives me 25 routes, and then I delete all the irrelevant ones.

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to include the version of presumably ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?

Comment: This does not sound like a closest facility analysis. This sounds 100k single route problems which would be an iterative route analysis model. Could you include a screenshot of data or diagram of what you're trying to accomplish? You may want to review a help file on [network analysis types](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Types_of_network_analysis_layers/004700000032000000/) or perhaps skim over some of the available [tutorials](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_the_ArcGIS_Network_Analyst_tutorial/00470000005r000000/).

Answer (score 1):

You want the shortest route between a point in one layer and a specifically paired point in another layer. This isn't closest facility, it's separate, individual route problems. The solution would be an iterative model/script which would create a route for a pair, dump it in a file, go to the next pair and create a route, append the new route to the holding file, and repeat. Closest facility is for grouping one set of points (incidents) based on their proximity to another set of points (facilities) - a one-to-many relationship rather than a one-to-one.