# Creating multiple routes at same time with different stop locations using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I have a feature class that contains about 500 cross-streets locations and another feature class that contains about 1800 locations.  I need to create a route from each cross-street to 1-6 locations.  Is there a way that I can set up Network Analyst or ModelBuilder to solve for multiple routes at the same time?  For example, cross-street A route to location 1, 2, 3; cross-street B route to location 4, 5, 6 etc.

There is an established relationship between cross streets and locations, and there is an attribute that defines that relationship. However the relationship is one to many: one cross-street to multiple locations that need to be defined by separate routes to each rather than just one route with multiple stops.

I was able to model the network but am having a hard time figuring out the iterate.  I keep generating networks for all points, not just the ones I specifically need: point 1 with point A; point 2 with point B, etc.  Here's a screen shot of the model builder showing routes I was able to create between Bell2 and OID 533; and Bell2 and OID 534.  Also on a side note, how can I change the attribute fields "FirstStopID" and "LastStopID" to recognize names of the attributes of the stops--e.g. Bell2 and 533.

[image: Network model]

Comment: That depends. Are A/123 and B/456 established relationships (and if so, is there an attribute that defines that relationship), or do you need the nearest six out of the 1800 for each of the 500? Depending on what you're trying to do, you're looking at Closest Facility, Location Allocation, or Vehicle Routing Problem analysis. See the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Types_of_network_analysis_layers/004700000032000000/) for descriptions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. There is an established relationship and there is an attribute that defines that relationship. However the relationship is one to many: one cross-street to multiple locations that need to be defined by separate routes rather than just one route with multiple stops.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Some of our protocols take a little getting used to, but the benefit is well worth the effort.  The area you have typed into here is reserved for direct answers to your question.  You are answering a comment that requests clarification to your question so the way to do that is to edit your question (see the edit button beneath it) in order to revise it.  In the meantime as a quick fix I'll convert your question to a comment but please be sure to take our [Tour] if you have not already.

Comment: I can't find the duplicate, but [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111816) is either what I'm thinking of or closely related. Basically you're looking at 500*6 route solves. It can be done in model builder. You'd need to either iterate through the 500 with a submodel to 'for each 500 iterate through the matching 1800', or just iterate the 1800 and select whichever of the 500 is attribute matched to each one. [This tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_6_Creating_a_model_for_route_analysis/004700000061000000/) might help you get started.

Comment: Also related (but no answer there): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100008

Comment: Thanks Chris!  I'll try this out over the weekend. Cheers.